# How can I exclude files from ESLint using the last modified date?

Tags: eslint

We would like to run ESLint on a huge legacy codebase.
The idea is to enable ESLint for each file that gets modified after a certain rollout date.
That way old files can stay as they are, at least until they need to be patched for a change request.
At which moment we have some time to fix the linting too.

From https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories
it looks like we would be able to create an .eslintignore dynamically as a workaround.

Anyway, we are wondering if there would be a better way.

Is there some extension point where we would just check the lastModifiedDate to include / exclude the file?

Or is there some setting/plugin that would allow for this?

Answer (score 1):

A different approach you might like to consider, would be to use Husky to only lint files that you are checking in to GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. These repositories are not on Git but indeed this concept might be a good alternative.